# Who adds the page to John's journal in Supernatural?

Tags: continuity, supernatural

In the episode, Wendigo, we see a page from John Winchester's journal about wendigos and on the opposite page a bunch of random symbols. Later on, in, I believe, Faith, Shadows, or Hell House (when they look up a symbol) they find that symbol on a scrap of paper attached to the page next to the wendigo page. They then look at each other, realising they've found the symbol, and their dad noted it down.

Have they been organising the journal? Or is this an error? It seems a fairly rookie mistake to me, if it is such an error.

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=File:Wendigopagejournal.jpg) is a screen capture of the first instance you're talking about.  Clarification question:  You're saying that the page opposite the Wendigo drawing had a piece of paper attached to it in a later episode?

Comment: I just skimmed through those three episodes, and as far as I saw they didn't even use John's journal in them.  Sam pulls out his own journal in Hell House for a moment, but we don't see inside it.

Comment: @izkata, yes that is what i mean. I may have the episode wrong however.

Comment: I think identifying the episode this happens in would help in answering the question. Unfortunately I've lent my boxset of the first three seasons to a friend so can't look for it myself.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist and Pureferret:  [This list](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=John%27s_Journal) of "Significant Journal episodes" should help in narrowing it down.  Any ideas?

Comment: Its not in those, as it was in season one that I saw it. I've not been able to check the episodes yet.

Comment: I've just gone back to Asylum. At 4.47 we seen Wendigo, then e second later they *turn the page*, which I missed. That's where I saw the added page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that a piece of paper has been sandwiched between those pages in the journal, rather than a new (bound) page mysteriously appearing, why wouldn't we assume that the brothers just stuffed one there? I imagine that throughout most of the first few seasons they are constantly pouring through that, looking for answers. Even into season 3 or 4, Dean's not certain why his father warned him that he may have to kill Sam. And even without that, his journal is a strong reference for many types of monsters. I think it's fair to conclude that they are, if not organizing it intentionally, then at least they're reading it heavily. Why wouldn't something get stuffed in as a bookmark when they're hurrying off to lord knows where?

Comment: Because the page that's stuffed in there is is something Dean and Sam both react too as though they've never seen it. I'll try and grab details tonight. Also dove kind of spoiled some stuff there...